# axios.delete is removing all nodes from firebase database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, rest, axios

I'm trying to execute a simple delete in my database with axios but instead it keep deleting the entire collection.

I'm keeping an idinside my node and I'm trying to delete a single object by the id I send, I tried both:

```
const removeFromFavorites = async (id) => {
    try {
        await axios.delete(`${url}.json`, { data: { id } })
        return id
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}

//// or 

const removeFromFavorites = async (id) => {
    try {
        await axios.delete(`${url}.json`, { params: { id } })
        return id
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

Both are deleting all the objects and not the specified one.
any one have idea why ?

thanks

[image]

Comment: Why is **id** in `{ params: { id } }` in curly braces? Should the value of **params** be an object, or just a number/string?

Comment: according to the examples ive seen it should be an object  : axios.delete(URL, {
params: { foo: 'bar' }
})

Comment: Oh, OK - then it's not a typo. Have you tried it like `{params: {id: id}}`?

Comment: What is the value of `url`?

Comment: firebastpath/favorites.json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should do this. If favorite is the main node.

```
axios.delete(`${url}/favorite/${id}.json`)
```

id which you will pass in the URL it should be the same which you want to delete. here id should be LIHSF..... which you will pass in an endpoint.

Comment: it still not workind .. the 'id' im trying to remove is a property inside the node , its not the id firebase generated

Comment: Can you post the picture of the node of your firebase to help you better?

Comment: yes i just added it to the post , please take a look

Comment: you mean you just want to remove that id "349727" from that object right?

Comment: no , i want to remove the object that contains the id "349727" but instaed - all the object are being removed

Comment: I have updated the answer like that. The id in the endpoint should not be "349727" instead it should be the id of that object. If you ask how can you get that ID? get the data using axios.get() and then filter it which id you want to delete instead of doing it with "349727".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197386/discussion-between-shashank-kumar-and-ishay-m).

Comment: @ishaym did you find a solution to delete the id? I'm in the same situation at the moment.

Comment: @Radu033 i ended up doing it in 2 steps, find the object by my id and then delete by firebase's id

Comment: @Shashank This is the soultion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

your id needs to be in the url like this...

```
axios
  .delete(
    "https://<firebaseDatabase>.firebaseio.com/favorites/" +
      req.params.id +
      ".json",
  )
  .then(() => {
    res.json();
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    err.json();
    console.log(err);
  });
```